# Which way is better to push a list into an empty array?

Tags: javascript

I have tested 2 ways of pushing a list to an empty array, I am not sure which is better so I gave 2 scenarios I tested.

What I want the push to do is the newly created task needs to go into an empty array, as the newly created div contains the info of the task created by the user.

JS Scenario 1

```
//variable of empty array that gets new task
let taskList = [];

//function that creates new tasks with date and time
const creatTask = (task) => {
  const id = createId();
  
  const taskNew = el.input.value;
  const taskDate = el.date.value;
  const taskTime = el.time.value;

const tasks = document.createElement("div");

tasks.innerHTML = `
      
<div class="task-content">
  <div class="list-of-task">
  <div class="task" data-id="${id}">
  <input type="checkbox" class="tick">
  <div class="new-task-created">${taskNew}</div>
   <label class="due-date">${taskDate}</label>
   <label class="due-time">${taskTime}</label>
</div>
  <div class="atcion-buttons">
   <button class="edit" data-id="">Edit</button>
   <button class="delete" data-id="">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>`;

taskList.push(tasks);

el.list.appendChild(tasks);
return task
};
```

[image]

JS Scenario 2

```
//variable of empty array that gets new task
 let taskList = [];

//function that creates new tasks with date and time
const creatTask = (task) => {
  const id = createId();
  
  const taskNew = el.input.value;
  const taskDate = el.date.value;
  const taskTime = el.time.value;



      const tasks = document.createElement("div");

      const listTask=tasks.innerHTML = `
      
      <div class="task-content">
        <div class="list-of-task">
        <div class="task" data-id="${id}">
        <input type="checkbox" class="tick">
        <div class="new-task-created">${taskNew}</div>
        <label class="due-date">${taskDate}</label>
        <label class="due-time">${taskTime}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="atcion-buttons">
        <button class="edit" data-id="">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete" data-id="">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>`;

taskList.push(listTask);
console.log(taskList);
el.list.appendChild(tasks);
return task
};
```

[image]

Comment: The only meaningful difference is *what* you are pushing into an array https://www.diffchecker.com/73l0ORff In the first case it's a DOM element in the second, you just get the HTML from the assignment as a string a and ignore the DOM element.

Comment: okay, thanks for that. How should I push the new tasks created into the empty array? That is the main question. is what I am doing on the right path? or is there a better way in which to do it